# How to communicate with the IoT hardware device and Server API

Tags: android, rest, server, iot

I am working with development of the IoT hardware device. I have done sample projects in the Android on [particle photon](https://docs.particle.io/reference/android/) device. Which was very simple for me. Just required 2-3 steps to connect with IoT device

Now my question is

1. How can hardware vendor develop the code which I can add as SDK in my android code?
2. Which framework will they use to develop the code?

I will expose REST API developed in Spring Hibernate.

1. How will they call HTTP rest API?
2. Will communication be done with the help JSON or MQTT?

My customer has suggested [this server](https://thingspeak.com/prices/thingspeak_home) to be used for API.

How should I guide my hardware vendor to start the work on SDK development? Or Is there any other way to do this?

Conclusion:
I can develop the Android code if SDK is provided even I can expose the Rest API which has been developed in the Spring, Hibernate. But, How hardware developer will develop the SDK and can use my exposed REST API to store the data

This project stores the data of water tank level of society. So, Members can check the level of the water tank on mobile whenever they want.

Thanks in advance!!!